# Why if my angular http post return ok, doesn't work subscribe?

Tags: php, angular, http, https, httpresponse

i am on angular frontend with a php backend.

Why if i do a http post with angular like this:
`Register.component.ts

```
 createUser(){  
 this.registers.roles = "user";
 this.registers.isnewsletter=false;



 this.registerService.createUser(this.registers).subscribe((response)=>{
   console.log(response);
   if(response.status===200){
    this.router.navigate(["/register"])
   }

 },
 err=>{
   if( err instanceof HttpErrorResponse){
     if(err.status === 409){
       this.error=err.message

     }
   }
 }
 )
```

}

`

for example if return the error 409 works and give me a 40' error message but if the status is ok and save my date on db does not work the code inside subscribe.

PHP file:

```
 try{
        echo("user/add trying");
        $db = new db();
        $db=$db->connect();

        $stmt_check = $db -> query($sql_check);
        $user = $stmt_check->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        echo json_encode(utf8ize($user));
        if($user == null){
            $stmt = $db -> prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
            $stmt->bindParam(":password",$password );
            $stmt->bindParam(":firstname",  $firstname);
            $stmt->bindParam(":secondname", $secondname);
            $stmt->bindParam(":isnewsletter", $isnewsletter);
            $stmt->bindParam(":username",  $username);
            $stmt->bindParam(":roles", $roles);

            $stmt ->execute();
            echo($response);


        }
        else{
            return $response->withStatus(409);
        }
```

Register.service.ts

```
export class RegisterService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  relativePath = "user/add";

  createUser(request: RegisterRequest) {
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.endpoint + this.relativePath, request);
  }
}
```

I would like know how can i do works code inside response on angular

ps. this frontend born in java now i' creating php backend, with java response works php doesn't

Comment: Could you provide registerService.createUser method code?

Comment: i modified it :)

Comment: Why does `$response` get output via `echo` in the if branch, but only gets _returned_ in the else branch? And why are you outputting JSON data first, and then, inside the if, something that is presumably _not_ JSON afterwards? You can not mix JSON and “normal” text output, and then still expect the receiving end to be able to decode that as JSON.

Comment: if you want to received a complete response use `{ observe: 'response' }` see https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response, else your API must return a json like,e.g. `{status:'ok'}`

Comment: i tried to return the response with return echo encode or not encodede but nothing worked, can you suggest me solutions? i ried a simple console print after subscription but it doesn't work do nothing after subscribe